# Showing Progress Bar while uploading to youtube using youtube's api

Tags: file-upload, youtube, progress-bar, youtube-api

I am using **php** version of the **youtube's api**. And I am using **Browser-Based Upload** (Directly Uploading to youtube's server).Videos are uploading fine to my channel.

What i want to achieve is show a progress bar while uploading, with **Uploadify**.Which i did well, while file uploading to my server.

Can you guys give any idea how to achieve a progress bar while uploading to youtube's server directly, could it be done with javascript? anything in youtube's api which can help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no feedback available from YouTube's servers for uploads, and isn't widely supported by browsers, the only sensible way to currently do this is to upload the file using Flash.

If it's possible, you'll need to configure Uploadify to run without it's server module and accept a 302 response on success (the YouTube video ID will be passed as a parameter in the redirect location).

Conceptually, it's certainly possible to do; I created a similar thing recently using SWFUpload (not the best tool for this job, but I was in a rush). Whether it's possible using an unmodified copy of Uploadify, I can't say.